# Find x position of UIView in a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I want to position a line in the centre of a UIView.

[image: the line is not at the centre of my icon]

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    if let anchor =  anchorView(){
        print("Anchor x origin : \(anchor.bounds.origin.x)")
        anchor.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        timeline.start = CGPoint(x: anchor.bounds.origin.x + anchor.frame.width/2 , y: 0)
        timeline.middle = CGPoint(x: timeline.start.x, y: anchor.frame.origin.y)
        timeline.end = CGPoint(x: timeline.start.x, y: self.bounds.size.height)
        timeline.draw(view: self.contentView)
    }else{
        print("this should not happen")
    }
}
```

I am getting x position of the UIView equals to zero

Comment: you can set x position of line like yourview.frame.size.origin.x + yourview.frame.size.width/2

Comment: I getting this error : "Value of type CGSize has no member 'origin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIView`'s `func convert(_ point: CGPoint, to view: UIView?) -> CGPoint` might be what you need:

```
let centerRelativeToTableView = anchor.superview!.convert(anchor.center, to: tableView)
```

Then you can use `centerRelativeToTableView.x`